# Is is possible to split a string across multiple lines in an Apache Ant build.xml file?

Tags: java, xml, ant

I have the following segment of code in one of my Apache Ant build.xml files.

```
    <property
        name  = "classpath"
        value = "${dir_google_api_libs}/google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:"
                "${dir_google_api_libs}/google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar:"
                "${dir_google_api_libs}/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar"
    />
```

However, if I try invoke Apache Ant on this build.xml file, it (Ant) effectively complains about the string being split across multiple lines. The exact message it gives me is;

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   file:/home/craig/source_code/java/Test_JsonFactory/build.xml;
>   lineNumber: 78; columnNumber: 11; Element type "property" must be
>   followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Does anybody know if there is a way to accomplish what I am trying to do, i.e. split the string across multiple lines? I detest having long lines like this in my build.xml files and find it much easier to analyse the code when it is vertically oriented and split across multiple lines.

Answer (score 3):

**What you have is not well-formed XML and so will not work with any XML application.**

The following XML is well-formed and shows how you might break up your long line:

```
<property
    name  = "classpath"
    value = "${dir_google_api_libs}/google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:
             ${dir_google_api_libs}/google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar:
             ${dir_google_api_libs}/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar"
    />
```

Note, however, that it would be up to the application whether the above XML with line breaks within `@value` is handled the same as the below XML with no line breaks within `@value`:

```
<property
    name  = "classpath"
    value = "${dir_google_api_libs}/google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:${dir_google_api_libs}/google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar:${dir_google_api_libs}/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar"
    />
```

In the case of Apache Ant, I've not tested the multi-line version above, but I wouldn't recommend it even if it did work.  Instead, I'd recommend the [**`path`**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) element:

```
<path id="classpath">
  <pathelement path="${dir_google_api_libs}/google-http-client-1.19.0.jar"/>
  <pathelement path="${dir_google_api_libs}/google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar"/>
  <pathelement path="${dir_google_api_libs}/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar"/>
</path>
```